# in which file AuthComponent::password method present

Tags: cakephp

i wanted to find out the file where AuthComponent::password method is present.
i have searched almost all files of vendors/cakephp folder, especially cakephp/src/Auth folder. i only found one method named password in DigestAuthenticate.php file but i echoed some text there to make sure but no output came. also i appended some text in return value but no effect.
so i confused in which file that method present.

can anyone please tell me in which file AuthComponent::password method present?
or which method of anyother file is called in the background when AuthComponent::password is called?

Comment: There is no such method in CakePHP 3.x, that's a relict from the past that exists in 2.x and earlier versions.

Comment: when i call AuthComponent::passwod('test') method it returns me a value, so its running perfectly but i am searching the actual code that is running

Comment: version seems 3.3.9

Comment: Then either `AuthComponent` doesn't refer to the class provided by CakePHP 3, as there simply is no such method, or the core code has been modified. `Error : Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::password()`

Comment: i have searched the whole project, i only found one password() method in DigestAuthenticate.php file, i mean if core is modified and this is the only method then if i modify the return value of the method then it should reflect in the value where i called that method. that's why i am confused

Comment: Sure, if the core would be modified it should show up (unless maybe it would be a weird modification using `__callStatic`)... this leaves the former possibility, `AuthComponent` isn't referring to what you think it is. `debug(AuthComponent::class)` / `debug((new \ReflectionClass(AuthComponent::class))->getFileName())`

Comment: thanks @ndm, i found the file name by using debug((new \ReflectionClass(AuthComponent::class))->getFileName()). it is in different cake folder(there are several unnecessary cake folder in the project that's why i got confused) that i missed to check. i found the version is 2.7.* and i found that function there. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of authentication you're performing. Note newer versions of CakePHP do not use this method, but instead uses different approaches.

Looking at the BaseAuthenticate, for instance, it uses [AbstractPasswordHasher's check method](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/source-class-Cake.Auth.BaseAuthenticate.html#134):

API: https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Auth.AbstractPasswordHasher.html#_check

---

Other authentication types and how they perform checks:

**FormAuthenticate**

Vendor path: Auth/FormAuthenticate.php

API: https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/source-class-Cake.Auth.FormAuthenticate.html#21-90

---

**BaseAuthenticate**

Vendor path: Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php

API: https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/source-class-Cake.Auth.BaseAuthenticate.html#23-272

---

**BasicAuthenticate (Digest)**

Vendor path: Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php

API: https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/source-class-Cake.Auth.BasicAuthenticate.html#21-115

Comment: That's not what the question was about, it was about a class method that shouldn't (and actually doesn't) exist.

Comment: The originator asks for where auth is taking place, ignoring the fact that this may have been changed in later versions. This answer shows this. Update: The answer now has an updated intro.

Comment: No, the question was about where the `AuthComponent::password()` method is declared.